# Do I need to go to grad school to make the largest potential impact on the field I’m interested in?

Tags: graduate-school, computer-science, research-undergraduate

I have a dilemma of deciding between grad school and industry. My undergraduate major is actually unrelated to what I want to do yet useful for everything these days. I want to learn about the scope of the field, but I’m not sure if self study or graduate school is the best way to learn.

I’m also taking into account opportunity cost in terms of time and money. I will say that I’m so passionate about the field I’m interested in that I would take working in it over somewhere like Google or a hedge fund. As long as I can feed and house myself I’m fine I think. I also have the option to just start my own project in this field, but I wouldn’t do that until I learn about the field first.

My major is Computer science at Georgia Tech, and I want to apply data science to the problem of reversing the acidification of the ocean.  Thus I’m considering a masters in environment engineering and then a PhD in CSE.

Comment: We can't evaluate what is best for individual people based on their personal circumstances. If you can edit the question to make it something that will be more helpful, it might be on-topic.

Comment: I edited and generalized as best I could.

Comment: Besides your personal circumstances, this depends highly on what fields you're talking about. Surely there would be marked differences in your situation for the pairing of actuary science undergraduate and pure mathematics for your true interest, as compared to the pairing of computer engineering undergraduate and 19th century poetry for your true interest.

Comment: Updated with the fields I’m talking about and the reason I want to learn more about a certain topic.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 your question might well be reducible to: What advantages does a PhD offer, compared to self-study in the PhD's domain? That question seems to avoid some of the criticism.